# How can i add UISplitViewController To UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my application. I have to use `UISplitViewController` and I want to do add `UISplitViewController` To `UINavigationController` but I can't do this.

I also know that inheritance of `UISplitViewController` is not possible. but it very important for me to add in `UINavigationController`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your question is not clear... What you exact want to do ?

Comment: i want to do, how to add UISplitViewController To UINavigationController nothing else :)

Comment: go for MGSplitViewController...

Comment: yup.. i also know that it done by MGSplitViewController but it is not worked properly in my app.. :( :( without MGSplitViewController it is possible or not ??

Comment: What problems are you facing with MGSplitViewController ?

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: a UISplitViewController must be the root view of an app (or perhaps more specifically, a window). It can not live inside a UINavigationController or anything else.

refer [can-a-uisplitviewcontroller-be-the-root-controller-in-a-uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723342/can-a-uisplitviewcontroller-be-the-root-controller-in-a-uinavigationcontroller) link

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to do this using the open source [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/).

Comment: yup.. i also know that it done by MGSplitViewController but it is not worked properly in my app.. :( :(

Answer (score 1):

You can add `MGSplitViewController` in delegate like :- in .m file

```
    self.splitViewController = [[[MGSplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    //
    MasterPage *aMasterPage = [[[MasterPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

    aMasterPage.splitViewController = self.splitViewController;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = aMasterPage;

    UINavigationController *navCntrl = [[[UINavigationController alloc] aMasterPage] autorelease];
    [navCntrl.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];


    DetailPage *aDetailPage = [[[DetailPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];               


    UINavigationController *navCntrl2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aDetailPage] autorelease];

    [navCntrl2.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [self.splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navCntrl, navCntrl2, nil]];

    [self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Q&A - [Is it possible to implement a Split View Controller within a Navigation Controller in an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014348/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-split-view-controller-within-a-navigation-controll)

This violates Apples guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH7)

A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface. Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.