# Is it possible to implement a Split View Controller within a Navigation Controller in an iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin

I'm working on my first real iPad app using Xamarin, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to navigate from the Detail view in a Split View Controller to another View Controller. The Master and Detail views are both tables, and I would like a row click on the Detail view to navigate away from the Split View and into a single view controller, not just the Detail view (which I've been able to do). I haven't found much on this topic, so I'm wondering if this is not a viable or suggested way of handling navigation in iOS.

The code would look something like what's below (using Xamarin - C#), but if I can get the Navigation Controller working for the whole Split View, I'm thinking the row click would have to be handled in SearchSplitViewController instead of on the Detail View Controller? If I place the Detail View Controller in a Navigation Controller, it navigates to the next page, but the Master View is still on the left.

AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationController rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController();    

SearchSplitViewController split = new SearchSplitViewController();

rootNavigationController.PushViewController(split, false);

this.window.RootViewController = new rootNavigationController;
```

Code called from SplitView Detail on row click:

```
MyViewController vc = new MyViewController(id);
this.NavigationController.PushViewController (vc , true);
```

Any suggestions or sample code (C# or Objective-C) are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. I'll have to re-design this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be technically possible, but it violates [Apples guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH7) and may cause your app to be rejected.

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain
>   navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view
>   controller you need to implement your interface. Split view
>   controllers cannot be presented modally.